# Automatically post on wall Using Open Graph Action

Tags: curl, facebook-opengraph

I use my own action type in open graph with custom value. The action is working, because I can see in my activity box, if I reviewed an item:

Ildikó reviewed xy item  in "XY" application.

However , I can't see anything else on my wall/timeline.
I mean I like to see a  post on my timeline, when I can see the item name what I reviewed,the first sentence from my review and so on.

I use curl to call the url :

The url is 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/appnamespace:review'; where appnamespace is my app's ,  and post the access token, this url, the item what I refer, and description(part of the review) .

```
$url =  'https://graph.facebook.com/me/'.$this->namespace.':review';

    curl_setopt_array($this->_curl(), array(
        CURLOPT_URL  => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'access_token' => $token,
            'caption'       => $review,
            'book'         => 'http://www.url.com/' . $id,
        ),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    ));
```

What did I do wrong? Do I need to call one more function to share in my timeline too?

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/) says it's totally enough to use the url above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your item url have the og tags so Facebook recognizes it as a valid FB graph object?

It might also help to go through my presentation [Developing Apps for Facebook Timeline](http://www.slideshare.net/chaffeet/developing-apps-for-facebook-timeline) Not well annotated unfortunately, but it does show the minimal set up required to get a timeline app working.

As noted in the presentation, you can also find [actual working code on github](http://github.com/tchaffee/fdgl-timeline-app), which might also help.

Finally, note that there is a difference between timeline and wall (newsfeed) behavior. If you post to the timeline, you'll always see it there (in either individual or aggregated form). Some of what goes on the timeline MIGHT go in the newsfeed. It's up to FB. They show what they think the user would be interested in.

Comment: yes, it has og tags. Unfortunately your linked documentation shows the old version of making og project on fb.

Comment: Have you scraped your page using the debug tool (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and does it pass with no errors?

Comment: Tildy, I compared my presentation (only 3 months old) with the current documentation for making an og project on FB.  I see no differences.  Could you point out any you've seen?  In any case, my app works!  It posts on my timeline.  Per the presentation you can look at my code on github.  Since your app doesn't work, maybe a careful compare of your code and what I have already working would help you out?

Comment: Please , please.  Definitely, I ALLWAYS try the pages on the debug page. And do not compare your 3 month old presentation, but try to create an og action in your app. You can see it looks like differently. Anyway, do you think , if I am able to see  this review in the ACTIVITY on FB, in that case the og is weird? I don't think ,otherwise  it will not be there. So the method of reproducate it: Create an og action ,  send to the facebook to approve, and after then create any function on your page which calls this og action. The result will be in FB activity, but not on your wall.

Comment: I just don't like, if somebody think, that I didn't try the "basic" things. In the other hand, I tried to use this custom fb action on many pages ,and it didn't went to the timeline too, it was only in the activity.  And I need to apologize, the documentation looks like different what  I have seen. Because I started on the dashboard, instead  of  the get started page.  That's why I didn't see same pages  as in the url was.

Comment: Hold on, do I need to add any "post" there , if I want to see on the timeline ?

Comment: Furthermore in your example  I can see the attend in the aggregation in the activity, but not as a  wall post .  AM I right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10796/discussion-between-todd-chaffee-and-tildy)

Comment: There is a difference between timeline and wall (newsfeed) behavior. If you post to the timeline, you'll always see it there (in either individual or aggregated form). Some of what goes on the timeline MIGHT go in the newsfeed. It's up to FB. They show what they think the user would be interested in.  I'll also add this to the answer.

Comment: The solution in Todd's last comment. It's up to fb.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable explicit sharing.

Click on the action type and enable explicit sharing as shown below.

Then you need to submit the action for approval.

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/submission-process/opengraph/guidelines/action-properties/#explicitlyshared